# Create an character list Features in TFrecords using tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

I write a code in tensorflow. I store the labels in a list called (***labels[]***). The labels list contains the characters. e.g

> labels[A,a,B,b]

I want to write the labels elements in  ***TFRecords file***.
so, I should declare ***features*** e.g.

```
def _int64_feature(value):
     return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))
```

my question is what should I use instead of the **tf.train.int64List** to be suitable for my case??

also, I used these two tutorial that shown bellow but I want another tutorial explain my problem please.

[TFrecords Guid](http://warmspringwinds.github.io/tensorflow/tf-slim/2016/12/21/tfrecords-guide/)

[How to write into and read from a TFRecords file in TensorFlow](http://machinelearninguru.com/deep_learning/tensorflow/basics/tfrecord/tfrecord.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFRecords are a type of binary format file. Hence, the aim is that the JPG images are converted into strings and then saved in the TFRecord. This enables quick reading.

This can be seen in the tutorial where first the image is converted into a `raw_img` using `image.tostring()`. Then depending on the datatype int64 or bytes this is saved in the TFRecord.

Since your images are JPGs i assume they are saved as bytes (0-255). So for every image in the list, convert it to string then the function `_bytes_feature(value)` in the tutorial.

Either save the height, width and depth in the TFRecord too or keep them as parameters as you will need these dimensions to reconvert the string to image.

For the labels you can convert the ascii character into its binary representation. This can be done:

```
>>> ord('a')
97
```

This is the number from 1-127 that represents the letter. This is in byte format and hence byte feature can be used once again.

To convert the letter value back to the actual letter all you need to do is:

```
>>> chr(97)
'a'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you for thses information it is help, but this is not  what I want. I do not have a problem with jpg image. it just explain what I do in my code. my problem is in the label and the  **tf.train.Int64List**

Comment: Updated the answer on how to go about the labels!

Comment: I updated my question to be more clear. and I will try use chr() and ord().
Thank you